# How to convert .doc or .docx file to .pdf file?

Tags: java, apache, apache-tika

How to convert **.doc** or **.docx** file to **.pdf** file using *apache Tika* in java ?

Comment: You can't - Tika converts to XHTML or Plain Text only!

Answer (score 2):

any specific requirment to use Tika. You can use Apache POI & itext API or document4j API that specially for doc conversion .

document4j Example ::

```
File wordFile = new File( ... ), target = new File( ... );
IConverter converter = ... ;
Future<Boolean> conversion = converter
                                 .convert(wordFile).as(DocumentType.MS_WORD)
                                .to(target).as(DocumentType.PDF)
                                .prioritizeWith(1000) // optional
                                .schedule();
```

Comment: yeah actually my project is using apache tika only and we don't want to use one more jar for particular this work, I thought there must be some way of doing that, but not getting any online support

Comment: Documents4j works perfect for me, easy and PERFECT conversion. BTW you should use not one, but many more jars to do this particular work. Dont be afraid of include more jars to your project

Comment: not sure and i have not try it personally . But Try below example instead of "html" try "pdf" for output . https://gist.github.com/amferraz/bded9e9b28f416d20943